# How can I get OpenCV libs to support Android 2.3.4 and 4.1?

Tags: android, opencv

I'm playing around with OpenCV on Android. I used to be able to get the sample apps to run on my Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.X but since upgrading to Jelly Bean 4.1.X they no longer work. I also tried to get the samples running on my Droid 2 with Android 2.3.4 which is also a no go. They do work on my HTC Evo 4G running 2.3.3.

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.2. I can see when the app starts that it tries to load libnative_camera_r*.so. It tries to load one of the following:

```
    07-24 10:15:24.394: E/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(6688): ||libnative_camera_r2.3.3.so
    07-24 10:15:24.394: E/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(6688): ||libnative_camera_r4.0.3.so
    07-24 10:15:24.394: E/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(6688): ||libnative_camera_r2.2.0.so
    07-24 10:15:24.394: E/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(6688): ||libnative_camera_r3.0.1.so
    07-24 10:15:24.394: E/CAMERA_ACTIVITY(6688): ||libnative_camera_r4.0.0.so
```

Its clear that the versions of the .so files pertain to Android releases. Android 2.3.4 and 4.1.X are not in the list and so its not loading the necessary lib.

My questions:
A) where can I find the necessary .so files? 
B) Are there steps I can take to build my own libs for those versions?
c) Can I trick the system into using previous versions like 4.0.3 for 4.1? (I'll be investigating this more)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to update OpenCV Manager on your Nexus and delete other packages for architecture